# Laravel leftJoin returns null from 2nd table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have 2 table `duty_sheets`

```
centerId | centerName | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | ...p22 | examiId
   1     |  xyz       |  1 |  5 |  8 |  7 |    1   |   1
   2     |  abc       |  9 |  1 |  6 |  6 |    1   |   1
```

and `feedback`

```
id | centerId | inspectorId | A  | B | C | examiId
 1 |    1     |     1       |  1 | 5 | 8 |   1
 2 |    2     |     9       |  9 | 1 | 6 |   1
```

here is my code

```
$center = DutySheet::select('duty_sheets.centerId', 'duty_sheets.centerName','feedback.id')
        ->leftJoin('feedback', function ($leftJoin) {
        $leftJoin->on('duty_sheets.examId', 'feedback.examId')
            ->where("duty_sheets.centerId", 'feedback.centerId')
            ->where("feedback.inspectorId", 1);
    })
        ->where("duty_sheets.examId", 1)
        ->where("p20", 1)
        ->get();
    dd($center);
```

to retrieve "All rows from DutySheet where p20 = 1 and dutysheet.examId = 1, and relevant rows from feedback depend on `centerId`, `inspectorId` and `examId`.

The problem is that the query return feedback.id as null while the record exist in feedback table with the ids.

Laravel version = 9

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in left Join

```
->where("duty_sheets.centerId", 'feedback.centerId')
```

This build a where against the value 'feedback.centerId'

```
duty_sheets.centerId='feedback.centerId'
```

You need use

```
   ->on("duty_sheets.centerId",'=', 'feedback.centerId')
```

Or

```
 ->whereColumn("duty_sheets.centerId", 'feedback.centerId')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read somewhere that ->where can be use in the closure function but didn't mentioned the difference.